# how to pass json query in Rest high level client in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

In Elastic search for retrieving data i tried to pass a json query through `apache http client` and  `elastic search rest high level client`, Is there any other flexible way to pass the json query using java API ???Any help will be appreciate Thanks in advance

---

```
String query="";
SearchModule searchModule..
XContentParser parser = XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON).createParser(new NamedXContentRegistry(searchModule
            .getNamedXContents()), query)
```

Comment: If you want to pass a JSON DSL query, you're better off using the [low-level REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-requests.html). Using the high-level REST client requires you to build the query using [the Java DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html).

Comment: is this okay to use low-level Rest client??

Comment: Of course it is. Even the Apache HTTP client is OK. It only depends on your use case and how you want to interact with ES.

Comment: @Val okay!! I have another qus if suppose am using Apache ES protected with credentials how come I will pass the username , pwd through Apache??

Comment: As described in the [Apache client official documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html) :-)

Comment: yeah got it..!! And in `rest high level client` we can construct the search request and pass the JSON DSL Query right??

Comment: In the high level REST client, you can b64 encode your raw JSON query and pass it in a [wrapper query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wrapper-query.html)

Comment: @Val ```NamedXContentRegistry``` we can pass a json raw  query  AND ```XContentParser``` it will parse the raw query correct me if am wrong...?

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: @Val check this